# Always heard, but never hearing

Tags: riddle, word

I can be seen, but not in person.

Always heard, but never hearing.

I can dry, freeze or warm,

Screaming, whispering, creeping, running.

You try to see which way I go,

But I change so much you'll never know.

Answer (score 14):

You are

> **the Wind.**

I can be seen, but not in person.

> You can see the effects of wind blowing, but the wind itself cannot be seen.

Always heard, but never hearing.

> You can hear the sound of the wind. Wind itself cannot hear.

I can dry, freeze or warm,

> Wind can dry wet things by evaporation; can freeze things (wind chill); and can warm things  (**[Sirocco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirocco)** for example, or the arid wind that often blows in the western US in summertime).

Screaming, whispering, creeping, running.

> Wind is often anthropomorphized in just these ways.

You try to see which way I go,

> You can try to **[see which way the wind blows](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/see-which-way-the-wind-blows-is-blowing)** - a common idiom,
>  (or - and I was remiss not to include it initially - **[this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ&t=43)** — thanks @n_palum!) ...

But I change so much you'll never know.

> ... but the wind is ever changing.

Comment: I'm disappointed that this riddle had nothing about body wind :-P

Comment: Running wind? Creeping wind? Never heard those before...

Comment: -1 for not quoting Rhapsody for any way the wind blows :P

Comment: Everyone's a critic. ;)  However, @n_palum, *that* critique is valid, and shall be addressed forthwith!

Comment: *Much* better :)

Comment: A puzzle, or answer, that tried to include every notable reference to wind in music would have to be pretty damn long.